# Line break in macro with > 9 parameters

Tags: math-mode, macros, formatting, line-breaking

I have a transition system where the transition requires many arguments to describe it. It ends up looking like this:

```
A \xlongrightarrow[a_1; b_1; c_1]{a_2; b_2; c_2} B
```

So naturally I have a macro that looks like:

```
\newcommand{\step}[8]{#1 \xlongrightarrow[#3; #4; #5]{#6; #7; #8} #2}
```

and I can use it like `\step{A}{B}{a_1}{b_1}{c_1}{a_2}{b_2}{c_2}`

The good thing is that when the rendered output gets too long, I can squeeze in a `\\` somewhere in the usage of the macro like
`step{A}{\\B}{a_1}{b_1}{c_1}{a_2}{b_2}{c_2}` meaning that I get the expansion that I want:

```
A \xlongrightarrow[a_1; b_1; c_1]{a_2; b_2; c_2} \\B
```

Now, however, I need exactly 10 arguments, and I do something like:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{extarrows} % defines \xlongrightarrow

\newcommand{\step}[9]{
  \def\tempa{#1}%
  \def\tempb{#2}%
  \def\tempc{#3}%
  \def\tempd{#4}%
  \def\tempe{#5}%
  \def\tempf{#6}%
  \def\tempg{#7}%
  \def\temph{#8}%
  \def\tempi{#9}%
  \stepcont
}
\newcommand{\stepcont}[1]{\tempa \xlongrightarrow[\tempc; \tempd; \tempe; \tempf]{\tempg; \temph; \tempi; #1} \tempb}

\begin{document}

\[
  \step{A}{B}{a_1}{b_1}{c_1}{a_2}{b_2}{c_2}
\]

\end{document}
```

which is amazing, but now I can no longer add `\\` in front of the arguments to force a line break.

So finally my question:
Is there a way where I can have more than 9 arguments to a macro, and still allow line breaks in the macro?

Comment: I'm uncertain about where's the advantage in using nine arguments instead of the more natural `\step{A}{B}{a_1;b_1;c_1}{a_2;b_2;c_2}`

Comment: why do you want so many arguments, which makes the source very hard to read (hard to see which is the 6th and which the 7th argument), why not `\newcommand{\step}[8]{#1 \xlongrightarrow[#2]{#3} #4}` and use `;`as in `\step{zz}{a;b;c}{x;y;z}` ?

Comment: oh no, I agreed with @egreg :(

Comment: Good point! I would like LaTeX to tell me if I missed an parameter to the transition, which I won't see if I have several parameters in one argument.

Comment: @MathiasVorreiterPedersen latex won't help with that. if you only do 6 parameters instead of 9 `\step{1}[2}{3}{4}{5}{6} next thing`  then you get not error it just gobbles `n`, `e`, `x` as the last three arguments.

Comment: Oh yeah, right. Hmmppff... I guess there's no real point to the absurd amount of arguments then. Thank you for making me realize this!

Comment: I don't actually think the number of arguments is the problem. \\ works as you intend in both your original definition and the new one if you use it an inline equation ($...$), but neither works in a display equation (\\[...\\]).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that a macro that checks the number of requested items is what you need. Here the default is 3, but it can be whatever is the normal requested number.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\step}{O{3}mmmm}
 {
  #2 % source
  \mvp_step:nnn { #1 } { #4 } { #5 }
  #3 % target
 }

\seq_new:N \l__mvp_step_top_seq
\seq_new:N \l__mvp_step_bot_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \mvp_step:nnn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__mvp_step_top_seq { ; } { #2 }
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__mvp_step_bot_seq { ; } { #3 }
  \int_compare:nNnF { \seq_count:N \l__mvp_step_top_seq } = { #1 }
   {
    \msg_error:nnxxx { mvp } { step }
     { above }
     { \seq_count:N \l__mvp_step_top_seq }
     { #1 }
   }
  \int_compare:nNnF { \seq_count:N \l__mvp_step_bot_seq } = { #1 }
   {
    \msg_error:nnxxx { mvp } { step }
     { below }
     { \seq_count:N \l__mvp_step_bot_seq }
     { #1 }
   }
  \xrightarrow
   [\seq_use:Nn \l__mvp_step_bot_seq {;\,}]
   {\seq_use:Nn \l__mvp_step_top_seq {;\,}}
 }

\msg_new:nnnn { mvp } { step }
 {
  Bad ~ number ~ of ~ items
 }
 {
  You ~ have ~ #2 ~ items ~ #1 ~ the ~ arrow ~ instead ~ of ~ #3
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\step{A}{B}{a_1;b_1;c_1}{a_2;b_2;c_2}$

$\step[4]{A}{B}{a_1;b_1;c_1;d_1}{a_2;b_2;c_2;d_2}$

$\step[4]{A}{B}{a_1;b_1;c_1;d_1}{a_2;b_2;c_2}$ %%% error

\end{document}
```

Here's the output on the console:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! mvp error: "step"
! 
! Bad number of items
! 
! See the mvp documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  

l.54 $\step[4]{A}{B}{a_1;b_1;c_1;d_1}{a_2;b_2;c_2}
                                                  $ %%% error
? h
|'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
| You have 3 items below the arrow instead of 4
|...............................................
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, that's a cool idea! I think I'll start applying this trick in more places.